# Group ring $R[G]$ semisimple if and only if $J = J^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, group-rings, semi-simple-rings

Let $G$ be an abelian group and let $R$ be a commutative ring and consider the group ring $R[G]$ of finite formal linear combinations of elements of $G$ with coefficients in $R$. Let $J = (1 - g ~|~ g \in G)$ be the augmentation ideal. If $R[G]$ is semisimple, then $J = J^2$. One way to see this is to consider the short exact sequence of $R[G]$-modules
\begin{equation*}
0 \to J/J^2 \to R[G]/J^2 \to R[G]/J \to 0.
\end{equation*}
If $R[G]$ is semisimple then this splits, which implies that $J / J^2 = 0$.

Is the converse true?

If $R = K$ is a field and $G$ is finite, I believe the answer is yes: $J / J^2 = K \otimes_\mathbb{Z} G$, which is nonzero exactly when the characteristic of $K$ divides the order of $G$, i.e. exactly when $K[G]$ is not semisimple.

I think (maybe?) that it's always true that $J/J^2 = R \otimes_\mathbb{Z} G$, but then I worry about whether or not the rest of the previous argument still works. For me, that argument is an argument about representations, which get very nasty very quickly when $R$ is not a field.

Comment: Another way to see it is to already be aware that *all ideals in a semisimple ring are idempotent* (because they are generated by a single idempotent.)

Comment: This topic (idempotency of the augmentation ideal) seems pretty interesting to me, but I'm not aware of any results about it. The first that I found that might be of interest is [this](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82503465.pdf) which I think unfortunately only deals with finite groups and $R=\mathbb Z$.  Might be worth following up the citation tree to see if there's been any new developments in the last 40 years, though.

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks for the reference! It seems to confirm that the result is true for that case (finite abelian groups and $\mathbb{Z}$). The case that I was mostly interested in was $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $G$ profinite, so some inverse limit construction should hopefully do the job.